# How do I run gparted as root?

Tags: root, gparted

I installed gparted to use for partitioning my hard drive so ubuntu is my only os but when I tried to run gparted, it told me that i have to be root but i am root as far as i know how do i know for sure i haven't even signed on as guest because i am still setting stuff up most other apps ask for confirmation i type in my password and on i go but gparted doesn't have that prompt how do i become root

Comment: Your subject line has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksudo gparted` then it will ask for your password and then it should run as root .

Answer (score 4):

If you run `gparted` in the terminal, you will receive this error message:

> Root privileges are required for running gparted.

I'm guessing that is what you are doing, though it is not quite clear from your question.

Either run `gparted-pkexec` or use the Gparted icon from the Dash, which runs the same command.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of Ubuntu, the command is:

```
gparted-pkexec
```

There's a bug that can happen in newer versions of Ubuntu where the gparted packages seem installed, but aren't. To fix that, you need to remove [gparted and reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/a/691681/2355).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pkexec gparted`. The desktop and/or launcher shortcuts already do this.

Comment: The shortcuts actually use `gparted-pkexec`, which is a shell script that then calls `pkexec gparted`.

Comment: I know but it falls into "implementation detail".