# GParted not working error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1

Tags: apt, gparted, shared-library

I can't run gparted.

I have purged and reinstalled and the error persists.

Here's the output of running `sudo gparted` in the terminal

```
$ sudo gparted
/usr/sbin/gpartedbin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install libgtkmm-2.4 and I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgtkmm-2.4-dev' for regex 'libgtkmm-2.4'
Note, selecting 'libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a' for regex 'libgtkmm-2.4'
Note, selecting 'libgtkmm-2.4-doc' for regex 'libgtkmm-2.4'
Note, selecting 'libgtkmm-2.4-1v5' for regex 'libgtkmm-2.4'
Note, selecting 'libgtkmm-2.4-dbg' for regex 'libgtkmm-2.4'
libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  debhelper gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gtkmm-documentation libatk1.0-dev libatkmm-1.6-dev
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libcairomm-1.0-dev
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev
  libglibmm-2.4-dev libglibmm-2.4-doc libgtk2.0-dev libgtkmm-3.0-doc
  libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev libmail-sendmail-perl
  libpango1.0-dev libpangomm-1.4-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5
  libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsigc++-2.0-dev
  libsm-dev libsys-hostname-long-perl libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev
  libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxml2-utils libxrandr-dev
  libxrender-dev po-debconf x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  dh-make libatkmm-1.6-doc libcairo2-doc libcairomm-1.0-doc libglib2.0-doc
  libgtkmm-3.0-dev libgtk2.0-doc libice-doc libpango1.0-doc libsigc++-2.0-doc
  libsm-doc libxcb-doc libxext-doc libmail-box-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed
  debhelper gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gtkmm-documentation libatk1.0-dev libatkmm-1.6-dev
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libcairomm-1.0-dev
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev
  libglibmm-2.4-dev libglibmm-2.4-doc libgtk2.0-dev libgtkmm-2.4-dbg
  libgtkmm-2.4-dev libgtkmm-2.4-doc libgtkmm-3.0-doc libharfbuzz-dev
  libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev libmail-sendmail-perl libpango1.0-dev
  libpangomm-1.4-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpixman-1-dev
  libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsigc++-2.0-dev libsm-dev
  libsys-hostname-long-perl libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev
  libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxml2-utils libxrandr-dev
  libxrender-dev po-debconf x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
0 to upgrade, 65 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 46.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 332 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

This says that it is already installed however it wants to install a ton of extras with a load of dependencies which I'm reluctant to do given that it says that the specific package that it is complaining about is already installed so have my doubts these extras would resolve anything.

How should I proceed?

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: It doesn't do anything. O to upgrade, newly install, remove or not upgrade. I suspect this is because it installs gparted without issue therefore as far as apt is concerned there is no dependency conflict which requires -f to be run.

Comment: I think you install this `sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libatkmm-1.6-1v5`

Comment: When I run those I get libatkmm-1.6-1v5 is already at the newest version, libatkmm-1.6-1v5 is set to be manually installed and libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 is already at the newest version. Now those first two are identically named packages therefore how can it say the first is at the newest version and for the second which is the exactly named same named as first package is set to be manually installed. Confused.

Comment: hmm try removing these packages  `gparted libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 pavucontrol ` then install them.

Comment: Ok that will uninstall ubuntu-desktop so it will take a bit of time to reinstall.

Comment: Not sure why but on mine when I selected those packages, copied and pasted to ensure that I got it right, and it did have ubuntu-desktop* as one of the removed packages. I went ahead and removed and reinstalled ubuntu-desktop without the * as I was going to end with every DE and package going. GParted now working. If you want to put your last response up I'll mark it as the correct answser. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Emonn Doyle will do. post as an a Answer glad i can help.

Comment: `apt-get install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5` will reinstall the package without uninstalling everything else first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try removing these packages `gparted libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 pavucontrol` type in this command.

```
sudo apt-get remove gparted libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 pavucontrol
```

and then install ubuntu-desktop if it removes it.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop gparted libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 pavucontrol
```

Comment: More libraries were missing on my side, @Pablo Rierra answer helped me fix them.

Answer (score 10):

Just after Bionic's fresh install, the missing libraries used by GParted can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libcairomm-1.0-1v5
```

Comment: If you got missing libraries in a fresh install, you should consider [reporting a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: This has been reported as a bug, see: [Missing dependency libgtkmm for gparted ](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1772317).  It has to do with Wayland.  See also: [
gparted does not start ](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1748989).  It has nothing to do with a bad install, as I ran into it on a fresh install.

Comment: @eyoung100 - double checked I was running without Wayland both in the installer disk and the installed system 18.04.

Comment: Wayland is the default in 18.04. If you removed it, that’s great, but gtkmm is still required.  See the [Ubiquity Installer Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1607687)

Comment: This worked for me on Bionic. Not very fresh install however.

Answer (score 7):

This command worked for me

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
```

Comment: In my case I do this for few more libraries, but at the end it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I had to do these two too `sudo apt install --reinstall libsigc++-2.0-0v5` `sudo apt install --reinstall libglibmm-2.4-1v5`

Comment: and on top of the last comment, I also needed to do  sudo apt install --reinstall libcairomm-1.0-1v5