# After installation applications listed as installed, but no executables found

Tags: apt, system-installation, software-installation, dpkg

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04.  There are several applications (e.g. **gparted**) which are listed as installed, but for which no executable exists.  The following diagnostics makes this clear:

```
# apt list --installed | grep gparted
gparted/bionic,now 0.30.0-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]

# dpkg -l | grep gparted
ii  gparted  0.30.0-3ubuntu1  amd64  GNOME partition editor

# apt install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gparted is already the newest version (0.30.0-3ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

# find / -name "*gparted*"
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gparted.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gparted.list
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-main/64x64/gparted_gparted.png
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-main/48x48/gparted_gparted.png
/usr/share/omf/gparted
/usr/share/gnome/help-langpack/gparted
/usr/share/gnome/help/gparted
/usr/share/doc/gparted
/usr/share/omf-langpack/gparted
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/gparted.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/gparted.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_CA/LC_MESSAGES/gparted.mo
```

*Related background info* : The installation was not standard - the disk is encrypted, and the boot partitions are on a removable usb.  Installation did not go perfectly smoothly but I did manage to create a bootable usb and can boot into the system.  I am running a browser, and have access to many command line programs.  But some applications, e.g., are not there even though listed as installed.

**Questions : (1) How can this be?  (2) How to fix it?**

---

Update:

Seems like this is a problem encountered by multiple parties.

[GParted not working error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/q/691672/723997)

[Missing dependency libgtkmm for gparted](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1772317)

[gparted does not start](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1748989)

I can report this is not caused by running Wayland or by running Ubiquity, as I didn't have either running on either of the live disk or on the installed system - Gnome / X was running on both.

After reinstalling gparted as suggested by @N0rbert the binary appeared.  But then multiple dependencies were missing and I had to repeatedly reinstall those as well to finally get it to work.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -L gparted | grep bin` to the question. Are you sure that your file-system is clean?

Comment: Please add the contents of `/etc/fstab` and `mount` to the question (with bootable USB inserted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be completely sure consider to check file-system for errors and then reinstall Gparted with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gparted
```

Afterwards use `dpkg -L gparted` (or its longer variant `dpkg --listfiles gparted`) with pipe to `grep` and you will get the following output:

> ```
> $ dpkg -L gparted | grep bin
> /usr/sbin
> /usr/sbin/gparted
> /usr/sbin/gpartedbin
> ```

See corresponding [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) for details.

As you may know - Gparted has GUI, so it is callable from *.desktop* file. You can find it with:

> ```
> $ dpkg -L gparted | grep desktop
> /usr/share/applications/gparted.desktop
> ```

and you can see that it is called with `gparted` executable

> ```
> $ cat /usr/share/applications/gparted.desktop | grep Exec
> Exec=/usr/sbin/gparted %f
> ```

Comment: But then why does his `find / -name "*gparted*"` does not list it?

Comment: This really looks weird, that is right. It is possible that `/usr/sbin/` is corrupted ...

Comment: Maybe part of the installation is on the USB stick and part on the HDD. I assume dpkg has some sort of database to keep track of what is installed and what not. Maybe that DB is corrupt.

Comment: @N0rbert - please see my update above.  The `... --reinstall gparted` was a partial solution